# Plotting polar function using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to plot this function using matplotlib.

[image: Desmos version]

As you can see in the Desmos app, the equation correctly plot the function as circle, but when I try to port it to Python, I got this instead:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fungsi_r4(theta, theta0, r0, a):
  return r0 * np.cos(theta - theta0) + np.sqrt((a ** 2) - (r0 ** 2) * (np.sin(theta - theta0) ** 2))

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
r = fungsi_r4(theta, 2.4, 5.1, 2.6)

ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.plot(theta, r)
```

[image: Python version]

My feeling tells me it has something to do with the negative values retuned from the function but I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: The radius is constant in a circle. Then you just need to define its value. Example: if the radius is 3.75 then use the `r = np.full(theta.shape, 3.75)` command.

Comment: If you really need this function, realize that the value of `a` must be greater than or equal to `r0`. Otherwise, square root of negative number will occur.

Comment: Thanks @Joao_PS but I want to know why matplotlib produces that plot from the equation because I have multiple equation that does not necessarily a circle (some are ellipse). Specifically I want to know what's the difference between Desmos and Numpy+Matplotlib when plotting something. And about the negative number, how  to treat them like in the Desmos app? Can I just ignore the negative values?

Comment: I've looked up parametric equations of the circle and all I've found use just one value for radius. This equation for `r` probably has some geometric or physical meaning beyond a simple circle.

Comment: Yes, it's actually part of a geofencing algorithm in one of my research team, not just a simple circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in how the two programs handle negative radii: Desmos flips them back through the origin, while matplotlib extends the radial scale into the negatives.

Here's some code to modify the data points like Desmos does:

```python
def flip_negative_radii(theta, r):
    flip_mask = r < 0
    r[flip_mask] *= -1
    theta[flip_mask] = (theta[flip_mask] - np.pi) % (2*np.pi)
    return theta, r
```

Example usage:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fungsi_r4(theta, theta0, r0, a):
    return r0 * np.cos(theta - theta0) + np.sqrt((a ** 2) - (r0 ** 2) * (np.sin(theta - theta0) ** 2))

theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
r = fungsi_r4(theta, 2.4, 5.1, 2.6)

ax = plt.subplot(projection='polar')
ax.plot(*flip_negative_radii(theta, r))
plt.show()
```

[image]

The gaps are due to the term in the square root going negative and producing NaNs. If possible, I would try to come up with a parametric representation of the function, which would avoid both of these problems.

Comment: Thank you! This is the explanation that I was looking for and I like the idea of turning the function into parametric representation to avoid NaNs. Can you give me some reference about creating parametric functions? My intuition says I have to create two function, which will return `r` and `theta` with the third argument as the angle and then plot them.

Comment: You basically define `r(t)` and `theta(t)` with `t` varying on some range (like `[0, 1]` or `[0, 2pi]`), instead of having `r` be a function of `theta` or vice versa. I played around with it a bit, and I think the most straightforward parameterization is just to convert the standard Cartesian equations `x(t) = x_0 + a cos(ωt)`, `y(t) = y_0 + a sin(ωt)` to polar coordinates, like https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1806019.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. For now, I think it's a pretty good solution, but I still need to solve that negative values because I have more functions to plot and much more complicated ones.